# Getting errors on the for loop `for i in range(n):` with the return int, not too familiar with python so im not sure if its syntax is an easy fix

Tags: python

Getting errors on the for loop `for i in range(n):` with the return int, not too familiar with python so im not sure if its syntax is an easy fix. "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function"

```
def function(x):
return 1/(x+4)

# function to perform Midpoint rule
def midpoint_integrate(x,y,n):
  step = (y - x) / n
integral = 0
for i in range(n):
  integral += step * function(x + (i - 1) * step)
return integral
  
lowerLimit = int(input("Enter the lower limit: ")) # input for lower limit
upperLimit = int(input("Enter the upper limit: ")) # input for upper limit
n = int(input("Enter the value for n: ")) # input for n

print()

if n%2==0 : # checking for n to be a even number
  print("Integral is equal to: ", midpoint_integrate(lowerLimit,upperLimit,n)) # printing the value of the integral
else :
  print("The value of n cannot be odd") # the program cannot perform Midpoint Integration if n is odd
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def function(x):
    return 1 / (x + 4)

# function to perform Midpoint rule
def midpoint_integrate(x, y, n):
    step = (y - x) / n
    integral = 0
    for i in range(n):
        integral += step * function(x + (i - 1) * step)
    return integral
  
lowerLimit = int(input("Enter the lower limit: "))   # input for lower limit
upperLimit = int(input("Enter the upper limit: "))   # input for upper limit
n = int(input("Enter the value for n: "))   # input for n

print()

if n % 2 == 0 :   # checking for n to be a even number
    print("Integral is equal to: ", midpoint_integrate(lowerLimit, upperLimit, n))   # printing the value of the integral
else :
    print("The value of n cannot be odd")   # the program cannot perform Midpoint Integration if n is odd
```

In python its all about indentation. The `return` statement should always be inside a function but in your question it was not indented inside the function. Also remember to add spaces, it could make your code look cleaner.

Either you can use this:

```
def foo(x):
    # ... some stuff here ...
    return x
```

Or this if your function is a one liner:

```
def foo(x):  return 5*(x)
```

But you will always have to check indentation.